# Elemental number theory -- Prove that if $ a | b $ and $ c | d $ then $ a + c | b + d $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Im a beginner at number theory and generally struggle with proofs. I can prove: if $d | a $ and $ d | b$ then $d | a + b$, with the axiom of divides.

I've tried using the same approach for this new one but now I'm totally stuck. I'd be very grateful for any help or maybe clues.

Comment: Did you really try an example? If found $2\mid 4$ and $3\mid 9$, but of course $2+3\nmid 4+9=13$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `proof-writing`? This tag is four doubts about the formulation of a proof.

Comment: Wow how epic is this. Spend 1 hour trying to figure this one out and only tried 3 | 12 and 4 | 16... I just assumed it was true after that. Lesson learned hehe. Thx for the help mate!

Comment: @ Jose. Thx. I thought this was proof writing my bad

Answer (score 4):

The problem is false. As a counterexample, take $(a,b,c,d) = (1,1,2,4)$. Perhaps you meant $ac \mid bd$?

Comment: Thx, no I'm just stupid :P